# How to specify Target Capacity for AWS Spot Fleet in terms of vCPU or memory in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

in terms of specifying a Target Capacity for a Spot Fleet the documentation is clear:

> You can choose to set the target capacity in terms of instances or a
>   performance characteristic that is important to your application
>   workload, such as vCPUs, memory, or I/O

However, when it comes to cloudformation, the TargetCapacity property is simply an Integer, as can be seen in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html#cfn-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata-targetcapacity).

**If I can specify only a simple integer, how is it possible to differentiate between a number of instances versus a number of vCPU for example? Is there any other property that complements the value of TargetCapacity?**

I am finding the documentation very vague when it comes to practical terms on how to properly specify Target Capacity in a more ‘advanced’ way in Cloudformation.

Any advise/guidance is appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Could be only available in console. cfn may only use instances count. CLI has [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-fleet.html) but they only include target capacity as instance count.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, following the examples from CLI might be the way to realise how to do this. If I eventually get to this I will share the CFN solution here.